# Freezing potato mash made with root and fresh vegetables

Tags: freezing, potatoes, mash

I regularly make homemade mash using the following ingredients

- Potatoes
- Sweet Potatoes
- Carrots
- Cabbage (2 varieties)
- Onion
- Leek
- Butter
- Cream
- Cayenne Pepper / Paprika

This is the first time I have made a 4-5 litre batch and would like to freeze it.  Will it be safe to eat despite having fresh cabbage mashed into the recipe?

Comment: Are you saying that the cabbage is uncooked?  Could you describe the process / recipe?

Comment: Hi @Joe - the cabbage is cooked thoroughly.   It is simply boil all ingredients, strain, add cream and butter and mash.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't much you can't safely freeze, and your mash looks pretty straightforward to me. As long as you're following USDA [safe freezing/thawing methods](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/freezing-and-food-safety/ct_index), I say, yes, **freeze on**!